# Send pageview in Piwik

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, html5, piwik

Sorry for this very basic question but I can't figure it out.

On my website I'm moving from Google Analytics to Piwik. I got Piwik working however, I can't trigger a pageview.

The main problem is that a page is loaded by javascript and ultimately being pushed to with a `history.pushstate`to the address bar.

For tracking with Google Analytics I could push it as easy as `ga('send', 'pageview', page);` But I can't find the same for piwik.

Any help is much appreciated.

JeroenED.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrestling with Piwik, too. Afaik, the most reliable way to talk to Piwik is through its global `_paq` variable. Track a page view like this:

```
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

However, Piwik does not seem to track a page view for the *current* URL, but rather for the URL it saw when it booted. So you'll need to update Piwik with the new URL before tracking another page view:

```
// Some history.pushState({}, title, url) here …
_paq.push(['setCustomUrl', url]);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

You might want to set the document title (`setDocumentTitle`) as well. Find an overview of Piwik's JS API [here](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript).